# Google sheets - complicated group by query

Tags: google-sheets, group-by

I have 2 columns of data. First is for Year(2019,2020,2021...) and second is for result(Won,Lost).

```
A.    B
2019. Won
2019  Lost
2019. Lost
2020. Won
.....
```

I want to generate a view like this:

```
Year. Won. Lost
2019. 1.    2
2020. 2.    1
....
```

I have a query

```
=QUERY(A1:B100,"select A, B, count(B) group by A, B")
```

which generates a view like:

```
year()      count 
              0
2019.   lost. 2
2019    won   1
2020.   lost. 2
2020    won   1
```

How do I modify it to achieve my desired view?

Edit: I tried the pivot query given in one of the answers. Got an error. See the screenshot.

[image: Query error]

But I have figured out an ugly workaround:

```
=transpose(QUERY(A1:B4, "select B,count(B) group by B pivot A"))
```

Comment: are the dots/periods in the real data?

Comment: @MattKing no they are not.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A1:B100, "select A,count(A) group by A pivot B")
```

[image]

Comment: Getting an error with this. See the screenshot in the edited question.

Comment: But I figured out an ugly workaround, shared in the question.

Comment: @simplfuzz what's the problem with the workaround?

Comment: @simplfuzz answer updated

Answer (score 0):

```
=transpose(QUERY(A1:B100, "select B,count(B) group by B pivot A"))
```